# Rename metric in Kibana 4.1 dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

On my Kibana dashboard visualization there is an aggregation metric that is "Sum of profit".  Is it possible to rename this field for the output to just "Profit"?   I have several aggregation columns and the "sum of" is not helpful and just clutters the UI.

I see a Json Format field under "advanced" but I do not know if there is a json property that is the equivalent of "AS Profit".

Answer (score 0):

This feature was present in Kibana 3 of configuring legend values, but unfortunately right now it is not present in Kibana 4.1 but it would be added in future versions of Kibana.

For more info check this link:- https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2534